# SimRank++ on a weighted graph (why the formula reflects the influncee of the weight)

Tags: weighted-graphs, statistics

In the paper "Simrank++：Query Rewriting through Link Analysis of the Click Graph"(http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/1/1453903.pdf), the formula to compute the similarity between $q$ and $q'$ is as follows:
\begin{align}
s_\mathrm{weighted}(q,q') =&\ \mathrm{evidence}(q,q')\cdot C_1\cdot\\
&\sum_{i\in E(q)}\sum_{i\in E(q')} W(q,i)W(q',j)s_{\mathrm{weighted}}(i,j)
\end{align}
[image]
[image]
The paper defines the notion of consistency : If $\mathrm{Var}(v_1) = \mathrm{Var}(v_2)$ and $w(i_1; v_1) > w(i_2; v_2)$, then $\mathrm{sim}(i_1; j_1) > \mathrm{sim}(i_2; j_2)$. But for the example in the  figure 6 of the paper as follows, the variance of flower and orchids in (1) and the variance of flower and teleflora in (2) are all $0$. Meanwhile, the normalized weight value of Teleflora.com in (1) and (2) are the same. According to the simrank++ formula, the similarity between flower and orchids in (1) and the similarity between flower and teleflora in (2) are the same. My question is that, how the different weights on the edges of (1) and (2) can reflect the difference of the similarity? 
[image: The example in figure 6]

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the question, and add the link of the paper.

Comment: There are quite some variables in that formula that are probably defined in the paper, but aren't clear here. It would be good if you provide a quick definition of all your variables, in particular $q$, $E(q)$ and $W(q,i)$ (is this the same as $w(q,i)$?)